# jquery hover handlerOut to execute callback for specific cases

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML structure as this with a constraint that it cannot be modified

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<div><a href="#"></a></div>
<div><a href="#"></a></div>
<div><a href="#"></a></div>
```

On hoverIn/ hoverOut on an `li` item, a corresponding `div` (with absolute positioning one behind another) will `fadeIn()/fadeOut()` which consists of some links.

Is it possible to modify the hoverOut handler in a way that it should execute a callback only if the hoverOut to hoverIn() is done from one `li` to another only?

In simple words the `hoverOut()` shouldn't execute the callback if the mouse pointer goes from `li` to any other HTML entity except for another `li` item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to fadeIn and fadeOut on hovering on `li` only. I have created the `hover` function as follows :

```
$('ul li').hover(
    function() {
        var indexes = $( "li" ).index(this);
        $("div:not(:nth-child("+indexes+"))").hide();
        $("div").eq(indexes).show();
    }
);
```

This will hide the div only on hovering `li` and will show when hovering on other elements.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2as6qgLp/)

Hope it helps you :)